# installing parcel failed in windows10

Tags: npm-install, node-gyp, parceljs

while trying to install parcel through npm in VScode, getting the below error.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user-id\ws-js-001\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.2.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking Python explicitly set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "--python=" or "npm config get python" is "python3.10"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3.10" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking Python explicitly set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - process.env.PYTHON is "C:\Users\user-id\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\user-id\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" is not in PATH 
or produced an error
```

The config value in config file is

```
C:\Users\user-id\ws-js-001> npm config get python
python3.10
```

Also the environment variable python is set to

```
C:\Windows\system32>set PYTHON
PYTHON=C:\Users\user-id\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
```

Could you please help me with the changes that are required to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`@parcel/watcher` is a native C++ package that `parcel` uses to monitor your project for changes and re-build when it sees them. To create the bindings between native C++ and node under the hood, it uses `node-gyp-build`. According to [`node-gyp` documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#configuring-python-dependency):

> node-gyp requires that you have installed a compatible version of Python, one of: v3.6, v3.7, v3.8, or v3.9.

So I'd recommend upgrading your version of python to one of the supported versions.

(Side note - it looks like `@parcel/watcher` includes a pre-built binaries for a number of platforms, including `windows-x64`, so that you don't need to build anything with `node-gyp` if you are consuming the package on those systems. My guess is that you're using 32-bit windows, because that doesn't seem to be included - is that right?)

Comment: Hi Andrew, the machine is x64 and has python 3.10. after updating the path environment variable to include python path, the parcel bundler package got installed successfully

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Strange that you didn't get the pre-built binaries. Were you using parcel 2.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

try use `npm i --ignore-scripts` or add `ignore-scripts=true` to `.npmrc`

Answer (score 0):

This issue isn't related python or vsbuild tool.
In my case @parcel/watcher is a direct dependency of another package. Solved by fixing version on that dependency.

So, here's the solution worked in my case.

In you package.json, add this line and try again to install.

"overrides": {
"@parcel/watcher": "2.1.0"
}